# Function find() works incorrect

Tags: c++, string, find

My task is to check if a number contains `8` or not. I've converted the number into a `std::string` and have used its `find()` method. But it only works with a number which starts with `8`, for example `8`, `81`, `881`, etc. For numbers like `18`, `28`, etc, it doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

unsigned long long g = 0;


int main()
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    int f = stoi(str);
    string eig = "8";
    for (int a = 1; a <= f; a++)
    {
        string b = to_string(a);
        if (b.find(eig) != size_t() && b.rfind(eig) != size_t())
        {
            cout << "It worked with " << b << "\n";
            g++;
        }
        
    }
    cout << g;
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve]. We need to see your code.

Comment: sorry, i asked only for my piece of code. My code solves another task, but i need answer only for find() function

Comment: `std::string::find` - "_...Position of the first character of the found substring or __npos__ if no such substring is found...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Comment: One of the cool things about the [mre] (MRE) is it's a distillation of some powerful debugging techniques, and making a MRE often ends early with the finding and fixing of the bug with no help from us. If you're asking a question and you don't already have a MRE or something like it, you're doing yourself a disservice.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `std::string::find()` and `std::string::rfind()` incorrectly.  They do not return `size_t()` if a match is not found.  They return `std::string::npos` (ie `size_type(-1)`) instead.  `size_t()` has a value of 0, so `find(...) != size_t()` will evaluate as true if no match is found at all (`-1 != 0`), or any character *other than* the first character is matched (`>0 != 0`).  This is not what you want.

Also, your use of `rfind()` is redundant, since if `find()` finds a match then `rfind()` is guaranteed to also find a match (though just not necessarily the *same* match, but you are not attempting to differentiate that).

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

unsigned long long g = 0;

int main()
{
    int f;
    cin >> f;
    for (int a = 1; a <= f; a++)
    {
        string b = to_string(a);
        if (b.find('8') != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "It worked with " << b << "\n";
            ++g;
        }        
    }
    cout << g;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto s = std::to_string(1234567890);
    assert(s.find('8') != std::string::npos);
    return 0;
}
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: I see where you are going, but the asker and those who follow may not. Please add a brief explanation of your solution and why it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).